# Missing Main Page Content Block in Blocks List

Tags: blocks, theming

I have the region for Main page content in my theme.info file which is `regions[content] = Content`. But still, in Blocks list, there is no Main page content block. This is causing me problems.

Can i re-create a new block with the same name. What should i do?

Comment: You also should modify page.tpl.php file of your theme to output there your new region. For more instructions you should give to us more info: at least what theme are u using?

Answer (score 1):

Recently had this issue. When I enabled my custom theme some files were missing and Drupal threw some errors and warnings. After adding the files everything worked fine except the Main page content block was missing.

To fix, I did the following:

- Set Bartik as the default theme
- Navigated to the block interface and configured the Main page content block (which was showing now that Bartik was the default theme)
- My custom theme was still enabled so it showed up in Region settings and I was able to select a region

Set my custom theme as the default again and all was good. Main page block was showing again.